# Calling a view through requests module does not create proper session data

Tags: python, django, python-requests

Supposing I have two views like below:

```
def get_session_key(request):
    return JsonResponse({'session_key': request.session.session_key})

def test(request):
    import requests
    r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_session_key')
    return HttpResponse(r)
```

1. Why will calling `get_session_key` on its own return a valid response - containing the session key - whereas calling this function from `test` through `requests` will return `{"session_key": null}`?
2. Is there a way to use `requests` for calling this view and still get a valid session key?

Comment: Because your `requests` has *no* session, it does not submit the cookies that a user sends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why will calling `get_session_key` on its own return a valid response - containing the session key - whereas calling this function from test through requests will return `{"session_key": null}`?

The session id is stored in a cookie, as is described in the [documentation on *How to use Cookies*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/):

> Django provides full support for anonymous sessions. The session framework lets you store and retrieve arbitrary data on a per-site-visitor basis. It stores data on the server side and abstracts the sending and receiving of cookies. **Cookies contain a session ID** – not the data itself (unless you’re using the cookie based backend).

Now if you make a call with the `requests` library, you of course do *not* pass these cookies to the system, hence you make a call without cookies, and thus without the session identifier.

You can however obtain the cookies with [**`request.COOKIES`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.COOKIES) when you make a GET request, like:

```
def test(request):
    import requests
    r = requests.get(
        'http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_session_key',
        cookies=request.COOKIES
    )
    return HttpResponse(r.content)
```

Since the session id is however *in* the cookies, for this specifies case, it does not make much sense to make a GET request.